# Codeigniter - Automatically escape SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Before anything else, I know that Active Record automatically escapes all queries by it and that there is a method for manually escaping SQL.

```
$this->db->escape()
```

The problem is that I am using raw sql queries sometimes

```
$sql = "...."
$this->db->query($sql);
```

but I don't want to manually call the CI escape function each time I do it.

Is there a way to make CI automatically escape all queries passed to it? A config that can be set maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

You may consider using the Query Bind which is at the bottom of the url.
Try to practice binding queries it is faster and cleaner way of doing.

**Bind Queries Example:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND price = ?"; 

$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 100));
```

Note** with binding method it is always automatically escape.